# Array Key same but add values to the vlaues?

Tags: php, arrays

```
This my array....  

         Array
        (
            [a1]=>'k'
            [a2]=>'a' 
            [a3]=>'w'
            [a4]=>'z'

         }

i want     Array
        (
            [a1]=>'k,a' 
            [a3]=>'w'
            [a4]=>'z'

         }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to add? Not all of us are going to read through your output and cherry-pick the items you want to add. Also, have you tried anything in your own code yet?

Comment: Is this an exercise in *spot the difference*? Can you please make explicit what you want to do?

Comment: This is the most basic in array manipulation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = ...;
unset($arr['Â 7'], $arr['Â 11']);
$arr[6]  = 7;
$arr[10] = 11;
```

Comment: based on the **spot differences**